# wget with sleep for friendly crawl

Tags: url, web-scraping, scrapy, wget

How to download from a list of urls and initiate pauses between each downloads?

I have a list of urls in `url.txt`, e.g.

```
http://manuals.info.apple.com/cs_CZ/Apple_TV_2nd_gen_Setup_Guide_cz.pdf
http://manuals.info.apple.com/cs_CZ/apple_tv_3rd_gen_setup_cz.pdf
http://manuals.info.apple.com/cs_CZ/imac_late2012_quickstart_cz.pdf
http://manuals.info.apple.com/cs_CZ/ipad_4th-gen-ipad-mini_info_cz.pdf
http://manuals.info.apple.com/cs_CZ/iPad_iOS4_Important_Product_Info_CZ.pdf
http://manuals.info.apple.com/cs_CZ/iPad_iOS4_Uzivatelska_prirucka.pdf
http://manuals.info.apple.com/cs_CZ/ipad_ios5_uzivatelska_prirucka.pdf
http://manuals.info.apple.com/cs_CZ/ipad_ios6_user_guide_cz.pdf
http://manuals.info.apple.com/cs_CZ/ipad_uzivatelska_prirucka.pdf
```

And I tried `wget -i url.txt` but it stops after a while because the server is detecting unfriendly crawling.

**How do I put pauses between each url?**

**How do I do it with scrapy?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### `wget`

```
wget --wait=10 --random-wait --input-file=url.txt
```

### `scrapy`

```
scrapy crawl yourbot -s DOWNLOAD_DELAY=10 -s RANDOMIZE_DOWNLOAD_DELAY=1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add some delay between each request with -w or --wait options.

```
     -w seconds or --wait=seconds
```